# React Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, ecmascript-next

I'm using property initializers. This is my state.

```
 state = {
 status: 'Simon Says!',
 compArr: [],
 color: 'red',
 userArr: []
};
```

This is my [pen](http://codepen.io/furball/pen/ybBgbZ?editors=0010#0).

I call the state here

```
game = (event) => {
 let compArr = this.state.compArr;
 for (let i = 0; i < compArr.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      switch (compArr[i]) {
        case 1:
          this.setState({
            color: 'green'
          });
          break;
        case 2:
          this.setState({
            color: 'red'
          });
          break;
        case 3:
          this.setState({
            color: 'yellow'
          });
          break;
        case 4:
          this.setState({
            color: 'blue'
          });
          break;
      }
    }, 1000 * i);
  }(i))
}
};
```

I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

How do I fix this in  ES2015+?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Define `const colors = ['green', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];`  and just call `this.setState({color: colors[compArr[i] - 1]})`. No wrapping functions needed.

Comment: ES7 was released *last year*. You are talking about an *experimental feature*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this doesn't refer to the correct context inside the setTimeout function ,you can do it the follwoing way

```
game = (event) => {
 var self = this;
 let compArr = this.state.compArr;
 for (let i = 0; i < compArr.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      switch (compArr[i]) {
        case 1:
          self.setState({
            color: 'green'
          });
          break;
        case 2:
          self.setState({
            color: 'red'
          });
          break;
        case 3:
          self.setState({
            color: 'yellow'
          });
          break;
        case 4:
          self.setState({
            color: 'blue'
          });
          break;
      }
    }, 1000 * i);
  }(i))
}
};
```

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmgVyy?editors=0011)**

You can simplyfy your logic by using an array

```
game = (event) => {
 var self = this;
 let compArr = this.state.compArr;
 var color = ["green", "red", "yellow", "blue"];
 for (let i = 0; i < compArr.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.setState({color: color[compArr[i] - 1]});
    }, 1000 * i);
  }(i))
}
};
```

Comment: you can also use arrow functions to achieve this without the `self` variable

Comment: @thedude yes that is also another way.

Comment: @Sulthan, Maybe not, because he is using a setTimeout function within a forloop , if he removes that function, he may well only get the last value in all the functions, by the way his logic can definitely be simplified as you suggest.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I meant the `function(i)`, I didn't even notice there is another `function()` inside :) You are right.

Comment: @Sulthan, no problem , :)